# How to get li width in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying li width in javascript. But not working...
Plz help me...

```
<ul>
<li>hello</li>
<li>hello</li>
<li>hello</li>
<ul>
```

javascript

```
var test = document.querySelector("li").width;
alert(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `width` with `offsetWidth`

```
var test = document.querySelector("li").offsetWidth; 
alert(test);
```

Or as per this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth), you can go for scrollWidth as well

```
var test = document.querySelector("li").scrollWidth ; 
alert(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var test = document.querySelector("li").getBoundingClientRect().width; alert(test);`